# gcloud setting up zsh alias

Tags: zsh, alias, google-cloud

I was trying to set up some alias command and function for gcloud.
I have written below function and running it in zsh in mac.
It runs fine when I pass `c` and `i` as individual arguments but not when I pass it is `ci`.
However, if you see below translation is same.

```
gcp() {
    local -A translation=(
        [c]=compute
        [i]=instances        
        [ci]="compute instances"
    )
    stg="stg-proj-12911"
    tst="tst-proj-1797"
    prd="prd-proj-817"
    
 
    local -a args
    for arg in "$@"; do
        if [[ -v "translation[$arg]" ]]; then
            args+=("${translation[$arg]}")
        elif [[ -v ${arg} ]]; then
           echo "project $arg has been set"
           #args+="--project=eval echo \$$arg"
           args+="--project=${(e)arg:+\$$arg}"
            #statements
        else
            echo "$arg"
            args+=("$arg")
        fi
    done
    echo  "${args[@]}"
    gcloud "${args[@]}"
}
```

I get below error when I pass `gcp ci list stg` as an argument , however it works fine with `gcp c i list stg`

```
ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'compute instances'.
Maybe you meant:
  gcloud compute instances
```

could it be because `compute instances` is being passed as a single argument to `gcloud` rather than two ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${translation[ci]}` is a single word (which happens to have a space character in it), but the `gcloud` command needs `compute` and `instances` as separate arguments. The best way to store a list of words is as an array, but you can't put an array into another array (whether they're plain arrays or associative arrays). So keep storing `${translation[ci]}` as a single string, but when you expand `${translation[$arg]}`, split it into separate words on whitespace. (You can pick any separator character as long as it doesn't appear inside any of the arguments you want to end with, but whitespace is intuitive and is the easiest to work with.)

Change

```
args+=("${translation[$arg]}")
```

to

```
args+=($=translation[$arg])
```

The `=` sign before the parameter name in [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) instructs zsh to split the string into separate words at whitespace. (More precisely, the word separators are given by the value of `IFS`, but unless you've changed `IFS` in your script, don't worry about this.)

Comment: Good Explanation @Gilles , Thanks